# Mod_rewritte - remove ?m=1 from url

Tags: rewrite-rules

Previously, in blogger, desktops were seeing my posts at

```
http://www.example.com/year/month/postname.html
```

while mobiles were directed to an automatically created mobile version at

```
http://www.example.com/year/month/postname.html?m=1
```

Now I moved to wp and using permalinks settings I configured my posts at the same address as previously

```
http://www.example.com/year/month/postname.html
```

My new site is responsive so I want to catch any

```
http://www.example.com/year/month/postname.html?m=1
```

requests and rewrite/redirect them to

```
http://www.example.com/year/month/postname.html
```

How can I do this?

I found a supposed solution [here](http://www.techgravy.net/fix-wordpress-m1-redirect-blogger-mobile-url/)

> simply go to .htaccess file, at right after the `RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /` line, add in
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
> RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]
> ```
>
> but it doesn't seem to work for me.

(edit: it works on a live site I tested it, but doesn't work on localhost, maybe it is the correct code but doesn't work on localhost?)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do anything (unless you have OCD about such things ;) )

You are not going to redirect to such address and it will die with time, and even if not, the canonical meta in the header will help google to avoid marking it as duplicate content.

Comment: +1 for putting it into perspective. I believe I do have OCD about such things ;)